# First Child not working on wordpress footer navigation

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-lists, css-selectors

Hey guys I'm trying to create a horizontal navigation on the footer of a WordPress theme and was encountering several issues. I tried initially doing it as a `display:inline` which got it to be horizontal, but i want every element of the list to have a bullet point except for the first element. So I did a little research and came up with the following code

```
.menu-footer li{
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
}

.menu-footer li:before {
    content:'\2022';
}

.menu-footer #menu-footer-navigation li:first-child {
    list-style-type:none !important;
}
```

However the first-child isn't working as I feel like it should be. I've tried moving elements around and such and it hasn't worked. The list is being created dynamically through the WordPress backend and no matter what I try it's not doing what I want it to do, that's why I chose to come this way and ask for some help. Most the solutions that I have found come from this site, and haven't found one that works for my situation. You can see the site at [http://goml.xxplosions.com](http://goml.xxplosions.com/) if you are looking for a reference point.

Comment: What are you expecting? Based on the code, there would be no bullets on any `li` since your first declaration makes it apply so. So how is `first-child` not working?

Comment: the content:'\2022' declares the bullet point. I found that here on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second rule creates a pseudo-element containing your bullet point in front of every list item. To remove it from the first element you need to overwrite that exact rule:

```
.menu-footer li:first-child:before {
    content: none;
}
```

Read more about pseudo elements:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Pseudo-elements
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3abefore)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the bottom.

```
.menu-footer li:first-child:before {
content:'';
}
```